# What are the products $\prod_{A\subset{\mathbb F}_p\colon |A|=n} \sum_{a\in A} \zeta^a$ equal to?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

This is a somewhat more explicit version of a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194343/prime-factors-of-sum-i-in-i-zeta-pi) I have recently asked.

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and write $\zeta:=\exp(2\pi i/p)$ (any other primitive $p$th root of unity will do as well). For integer $n\in[0,p]$, the products
  $$ {\mathcal P}_p(n) := \prod_{\substack{A\subseteq{\mathbb F}_p \\ |A|=n}}\  \sum_{a\in A} \zeta^a $$
are rational integers; can they be found "explicitly"?

It is immediately seen that ${\mathcal P}_p(0)=0$ and ${\mathcal P}_p(1)=1$, and I can show that ${\mathcal P}_p(2)=\left(\frac2p\right)$ (it is not difficult to see that ${\mathcal P}_p(2)=\pm 1$, but to determine the sign is trickier). Also, we have ${\mathcal P}_p(p-n)=(-1)^{\binom{p}{n}}{\mathcal P}_p(n)$, so that ${\mathcal P}_p(p)=0$, ${\mathcal P}_p(p-1)=-1$, and ${\mathcal P}_p(p-2)=\pm 1$.

> $\quad$ What are the values of ${\mathcal P}_p(n)$ for $n\in[3,p-3]$?

Some numerical data (thanks to Talmon Silver for the programming):

$\quad {\mathcal P}_5(3)=-1$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_7(3)=-2^7$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_{11}(3)=23^{11}$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_{13}(3)=159^{13}$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_{17}(3)=-24617^{17}$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_{19}(3)=-611009^{19}$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_{23}(3)=1265401351^{23}$

> $\quad$ If finding the individual values ${\mathcal P}_p(n)$ is difficult, can we at least find explicitly  the product
>     $$ {\mathcal P}_p(1){\mathcal P}_p(2)\dotsb{\mathcal P}_p(p-2){\mathcal P}_p(p-1) 
>        = \prod_{\varnothing\ne A\subsetneq{\mathbb F}_p} \sum_{a\in A} \zeta^a \ ?$$

Denoting this product by ${\mathcal P}_p$,

$\quad {\mathcal P}_3=-1$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_5=-1$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_7=-2^{14}$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_{11}=-(3\cdot 23^4 \cdot 67\cdot 89)^{22}$
$\quad {\mathcal P}_{13}=-(3^{12}\cdot 5\cdot 53^6 \cdot 79^4\cdot 131^2 \cdot 157^2 \cdot 313\cdot 547\cdot 599\cdot 911)^{26}$

---

The problem can be restated in a purely combinatorial way, as hinted to in Ofir's comment below. Write $N:=\binom pn$, let $A_1,\dotsc,A_N$ be all the $n$-element subsets of ${\mathbb F}_p$, and for $z\in{\mathbb F}_p$ denote by $r_n(z)$ the number of representations $z=a_1+\dotsb+ a_N$ with $a_1\in A_1,\dotsc, a_N\in A_N$. We have then ${\mathcal P}_p(n)=\sum_{z\in{\mathbb F}_p}r_n(z)\zeta^z$, and from the fact that ${\mathcal P}_p(n)$ is an integer, it follows that $r_n(z)$ are actually equal to each other for all $z\in{\mathbb F}_p\setminus\{0\}$; as a result, we have, say, ${\mathcal P}_p(n)=r_n(0)-r_n(1)$. On the other hand, 
  $$ r_n(0)+(p-1)r_n(1) = \sum_{z\in{\mathbb F}_p} r_n(z) = |A_1|\dotsb|A_N| = n^{\binom pn}. $$ 
This yields 
  $$ {\mathcal P}_p(n) = \frac1{p-1} \left( p\,r_n(0)-n^{\binom pn}\right). $$
Thus, the problem boils down to finding $r_n(0)$, the number of all zero-sum $N$-tuples
$(a_1,\dotsc,a_N)$ with the components $a_i$ representing each of the $n$-element subsets of ${\mathbb F}_p$.

Comment: Two observations:
1. This is, in a way, the "dual" of the coefficients of $x^p-1 = \prod_{a=0}^{p-1} (x- \zeta^a)$, which are (up to sign) $\sum_{ A\subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p}, |A|=n} \prod_{a \in A} \zeta ^a$.
2. The case $n=1$ is related to $N(\zeta)=1$, the case $n=2$ to $N(1+\zeta) = 1$ (for $p \neq 2$). The case $n=-3$ is related to $N((1+\zeta)^p+1)$, which is computable mod $p$ as 1.

Comment: Up to sign, they appear to be powers of primes, at least for p, n small. I notice $2^7$, $3^8$, $11^{10}$, and $19^9$ cropping up. In particular, $\mathcal{P}_p(n)$ appears to be zero or of the form $\pm q^p$ for $q$ apparently prime (or unity).

Comment: I can calculate ${\mathcal P}_p(n) \mod p$ (it's usually 1). Let $A_{1}, \cdots, A_{\binom{p}{n}}$ be the subsets of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ of size $n$. If we let $X_i$ denote number of solutions to $a_1 + \cdots + a_{\binom{p}{n}} = i \mod p$ for $a_j \in A_j$, we see that ${\mathcal P}_p(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} X_i \zeta^i$. Since this must be an integer, $X_i$ is constant for $i \neq 0$, and we find ${\mathcal P}_p(n) = X_0 - X_1$. On the other hand, $n^{\binom{p}{n}} = \sum X_i = X_0 + (p-1)X_1 \equiv X_0 - X_1 \mod p$, hence ${\mathcal P}_p(n)\equiv n^{\binom{p}{n}} \mod p$.

Comment: (cont.) And if $n>1,(n,p-1)=1$, we find $\binom{p}{n} \equiv \binom{1}{n} = 0 \mod (p-1)$, hence $n^{\binom{p}{n}} \equiv n^0 = 1 \mod p$.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman I can explain the $p$'th power phenomena. Let $X=\sum_{a \in A} \zeta^a$ be one of the sums appearing in the product. Let $X_{\Delta} = \sum_{a \in A} \zeta^{a+\Delta} = \zeta^{\Delta} X$ be another sum appearing in the product and corresponding to $A+\Delta$. The sums $\{ X+\Delta\}_{\Delta=0}^{p-1}$ are distinct (assuming $0<n<p$), and their product is a $p$'th power of an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$, as $\prod_{\Delta=0}^{p-1} X_{\Delta} = X_{\Delta}^{p} \zeta^{\binom{p}{2}} = X_{\Delta}^{p}$.

Comment: (cont.) Hence, $\mathcal{P}_{p}(n)^{p-1} = N(\mathcal{P}_{p}(n)) = N(a^p) = N(a)^p$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. As $N(a)$ is an integer, we find $\mathcal{P}_{p}(n)$ is a $p$'th power.

Comment: @Steve Huntsman: Looks like you have some computations done; could you post here the results? What $p$ and $n$ the values you list ($2^7,3^8,11^{10},19^9$) correspond to? (In fact, I am a bit puzzled: say, having ${\mathcal P}_p(n)=3^8$ doesn't agree with ${\mathcal P}_p(n)$ being a $p$th power, see Ofir's comment.)

Comment: @Seva, oh, you're right. The $11^{10}$ example would be in conflict, but I didn't restrict $p$ to be prime or even a prime power. This took me only five lines of MATLAB that could fit here, but it will have to wait until I remember to post it from a computer elsewhere.

Comment: @Ofir: In fact, it is not true in general that $\binom pn\equiv 0\pmod{p-1}$. Also, please consider fixing some typos in your proof that ${\mathcal P}_p(n)$ is a $p$th power.

Comment: @Seva You're right, evaluating $\binom{p}{n} \mod (p-1)$ is trickier than I thought. Unfortunately, I can't edit comments (they get "locked" after a few minutes) - sorry...

Comment: A question of a similar spirit is considered in G. Myerson's papers *A combinatorial problem in finite groups I, II*. The first of these is in the Pacific Journal of Math., vol. 82 (1979), pp. 179-187; the second in Quart. J. Math. Oxford, vol. 31 (1980), pp. 219-231.

Comment: @Vesselin Dimitrov: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: More values of the function $p\mapsto {\cal P}_p(3)$, starting from $p=3$ and giving 
values for $p=3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, \dots, $31$
$$0, -1, -1, 0, -2^7, -3^8, 0, 11^{10}, 23^{11}, 0, 159^{13}, 464^{14}, 0, -6069^{16},
-24617^{17},0,-611009^{19}, -3438875^{20}, 0, 162222611^{22}, 1265401351^{23}, 0,
113562774001^{25}, 1226797460541^{26}, 0, -209594542523392^{28}, 3134065080817441^{29},
0, -1019802203023098400^{31}$$

Comment: The number ${\cal P}_{31}(4)= M^{31}$ where $M$ is a number of 163 digits. 
$M=2^{35} \times 5^9\times 311^4\times 373\times \cdots \times 1620371$ with prime
factors  $p\equiv 1\bmod31$.

Comment: My quick and dirty MATLAB code was "z = exp(2*pi*i/p); A = nchoosek(1:p,n); S = sum(z.^A,2); P = prod(S);" and this was supplemented by OEIS. Of course a symbolic approach is really better here...

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial answer:

I can prove that ${\cal P}_p(3)=\epsilon_p v_p^p$, with $\varepsilon_p^2=1$, for every integer $p\ge 3$ (not necessarily prime). The proof is too technical to present here.
The values of $v_p$ are given by
$$ v_p^6=\frac{9W_p}{(2^p-(-1)^p)^2(1-(-2)^p)}, $$
where 
$$ W_p=\prod_\zeta\{(1+\zeta)^p-(-1)^p\}; $$
except for the sign these $W_p$ are the numbers of sequence A096964 in OEIS 
(Wendt's determinant).

Also $W_p=\det(M+(1-(-1)^p) I)$ where $M$ is the circulant matrix 
with first line $\binom{p}{k}$ for $0\le k\le p-1$.

The sequence $\varepsilon_p$ appear to have a simple periodic structure, but 
this I have not proved.

Comment: @Seva  My formulas are valid for any natural number $p\ge3$.

Comment: Since your $v_p$ seems to be defined only up to a 6th root of unity, why do you also need to include $\epsilon_p$ before it?

Comment: @Seva If my computation are correct, $v_p^6$ is a positive real number for $p$ odd. So I take its positive $6$-root and then only remain a sign.

Comment: @Seva I will send you my computation if I find your email.

Comment: @Seva  I tried the email address in your web page. But my message is not send. I am not sure what is the problem. Perhaps if you send a mail to me I can answer to it.